How to generate multiple CSV files on source transformer in one go?
I am trying to generate a CSV file from rows returned by a select query on the source transformer. Here are the steps I want to perform:

Get Placer_Order_Numbers values from ORDER table against OrderID.
For each Placer_Order_Numbers value, execute another select query to get OrderID, Patient_Last_Name, and Patient_First_Name from ORDER_DETAILS table and generate a CSV file for all the rows returned by the 2nd select query.
Put the generated CSV in channelMap and pass to the destination to be written to SFTP Location.

However, each time I execute the channel, the resultant CSV only has the row returned by the last query inside the while loop.
try
{
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**.**.**.**:****/dbname','user','password');
   
    getPlacerOrderNumber = dbConnMirth.executeCachedQuery(" SELECT * PLACER_ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDER WHERE ORDER_ID IN (11055,11054,11053); ");
    
    if (getPlacerOrderNumber.size() > 0){
        
        while(getPlacerOrderNumber.next()){
            
            var resultOrderDetailsQuery = "SELECT ORDER_DETAIL_ID,PATIENT_LAST_NAME, PATIENT_FIRST_NAME FROM ORDER_DETAILS WHERE ORDER_DETAILS_PLACER_ORDER_NUMBER = '" + placerOrderNumber + "'; ";
            var resultOrderDetailsQueryResult = dbConn.executeCachedQuery(resultOrderDetailsQuery);
            
            if (resultOrderDetailsQueryResult.size() > 0){
                resultOrderDetailsQueryResult.next();
                
                var orderDetailId = resultOrderDetailsQueryResult.getInt(1);
                var patientFirst = resultOrderDetailsQueryResult.getString(4);
                var patientLast = resultOrderDetailsQueryResult.getString(3);
                var csvName = patientLast + "_" + patientFirst + ".csv";
                
                channelMap.put('csvName', csvName);
                
                csv = 'Order Detail Id' + delimiter + 'Patient Last Name' + delimiter + 'Patient First Name' + delimiter +'\n';
                csv = csv + orderDetailId + delimiter+ patientLast + delimiter + patientFirst +'\n';
            }
            channelMap.put('csv', csv);
        }
    }
}

Am I doing something wrong while passing the CSV in transformer step? Any expert suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Reading the code I see that you only return the last element.
Try to move the line
 csv = 'Order Detail Id' + delimiter + 'Patient Last Name' + delimiter + 'Patient First Name' + delimiter +'\n';

before the "while" statement, because inside the while it's deleting prior content
